# dbt and BigQuery : dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt

Have the following BigQuery request which is perfectly working on the BigQuery console :

> DECLARE dynamic_sql STRING; SET dynamic_sql = ( SELECT
> STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CONCAT(' MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = "',
> field_name, '" THEN field_value END) AS `', REGEXP_REPLACE(field_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]', '_')), '`, ') FROM jira.all_latest_fields );
>
> SET dynamic_sql = CONCAT('SELECT issue_id, ', dynamic_sql, '` FROM
> jira.all_latest_fields GROUP BY issue_id');
>
> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dynamic_sql;

I need to implement this one in dbt, I have the following request but it's not working :

> {{ config(materialized='table') }}
>
> {% set dynamic_sql_query %}   SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT
> CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = "', field_name, '" THEN field_value
> END) AS `', REGEXP_REPLACE(field_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]', '_')), '`, ') AS sql_columns   FROM {{ ref('jira_all_latest_fields') }} {% endset %}
>
> {% set dynamic_query %}   SELECT issue_id, {{
> (adapter.query(dynamic_sql_query)).rows[0].sql_columns }}   FROM {{
> ref('jira_all_latest_fields') }}   GROUP BY issue_id {% endset %}
>
> {% do adapter.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {{ this }}") %}
>
> {% do adapter.execute("CREATE TABLE {{ this }} AS (" ~ dynamic_query ~
> ")") %}

Got the following error :
09:18:12  Compilation Error in model jira_custops (models/jira_custops.sql)
09:18:12    'dbt.context.providers.RuntimeDatabaseWrapper object' has no attribute 'query'. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".

I have tried with ChatGPT without success

Answer (score -1):

The error is very straightforward, the object `adapter` has no method `query`.

I think you want the [`run_query`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) macro. Also, since you're using `materialized=table`, you don't need to create the table manually:

```sql
{{ config(materialized='table') }}

{% set dynamic_sql_query %} 
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = "', field_name, '" THEN field_value END) AS ', REGEXP_REPLACE(field_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]', '_')), ', ') AS sql_columns FROM {{ ref('jira_all_latest_fields') }} 
{% endset %}

{% set dynamic_columns = run_query(dynamic_sql_query).rows[0].sql_columns %}

SELECT issue_id, {{ dynamic_columns }} 
FROM {{ ref('jira_all_latest_fields') }} GROUP BY issue_id
```

Comment: Thanks but still got an error : 
dbt run --models +jira_custops
14:41:29  Running with dbt=1.5.1
14:41:30  Unable to do partial parsing because saved manifest not found. Starting full parse.
14:41:32  Encountered an error:
Compilation Error in model jira_custops (models/jira_custops.sql)
  'None' has no attribute 'table'. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".

Comment: It seems that the issue is linked to the macro run_query, any idea or alternative ?